# Navigator gets the wrong context

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter application which shows a camera, then scans a qr-code using git://github.com/arashbi/flutter_qrcode_reader and on the call back, I want to navigate to another screen to show the information I get from some query. The problem is, it seems Navigator get a wrong context, so instead of full page navigation, I see the second page pushed inside my first page as a widget.

The build of first page is as follow :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget main =
    new Scaffold(
      appBar: _buildAppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          _eventButton ?? new Text(""),
          new Center(
              child: new Text("Hi"))
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: 
            () {
          new QRCodeReader()
              .setAutoFocusIntervalInMs(200)
              .setForceAutoFocus(true)
              .setTorchEnabled(true)
              .setHandlePermissions(true)
              .setExecuteAfterPermissionGranted(true)
              .scan().then((barcode) => _showTicketPage(barcode));
        }
        ,
        child: new Icon(Icons.check),
      ),
    );
    if (!_loading) {
      return main;
    } else {
      return new Stack(
          children: [main,
          new Container(

              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(220, 220, 220,
                      0.3) // Specifies the background color and the opacity
              ),
              child: new Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),))
          ]
      );
    }
  }
```

The 'Hi' Widget is for debugging, and the navigate method is

```
   void _showTicketPage(var barcode) {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => TicketScreen(barcode)));
    }
```

After getting the barcode, the second screen - TicketScreen - is pushed under 'Hi' Widget. I didn't even know this was possible to do.

I tried to get the context of the screen, save it to a field var, but that didn't help either.

How can I fix it? I ran out of ideas.

Comment: The first sentence seems to be missing something "I have a which shows a camera"

Comment: I can't really see where you get the context from which you use in _showTicketPage, but that context should already contain the Scaffold I think. Maybe it will fix it if you put everything in the body in a separate widget? With flutter I like to keep my widgets small and with a single purpose. The inner widget will get the right context that way.

Comment: It doesn't really. I tried that. When I debug, the context belongs to the page, but that is the first context. I am not sure where the builder gets its content from. I also tried with different plugin in a different very simple setup, didn't work

Comment: Context is already in the  state class

Comment: I do have the exact same issue... Did you find a workaround, by any chance ?

Comment: I did find a solution. The problem is that the navigation happens in the middle of page render, so the context is simply wrong look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49867066/navigating-from-a-plugin-callback for solutions.