# Navigating from a plugin callback

Tags: flutter

The problem is when I want to navigate from a callback - which is invoked by plugin - new page is pushed in as a widget inside my page.

This is the code:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:barcode_scan/barcode_scan.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyApp(),
  ) );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String barcode = "";

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text('Barcode Scanner Example'),
          ),
          body: new Center(
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  child: new MaterialButton(
                      onPressed: scan, child: new Text("Scan")),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ));
  }

  Future scan() async {
    try {
      String barcode = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
      print("${context}");
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return new BarcodePage(barcode);}
          ));

      setState(() => this.barcode = barcode);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied) {
        setState(() {
          this.barcode = 'The user did not grant the camera permission!';
        });
      } else {
        setState(() => this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e');
      }
    } on FormatException{
      setState(() => this.barcode = 'null (User returned using the "back"-button before scanning anything. Result)');
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() => this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e');
    }
  }
}

class BarcodePage extends StatefulWidget {
  BarcodePage(String s) {
    str = s;
  }
  String str;
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _BarcodePageState(str);
  }

}
class _BarcodePageState extends State<BarcodePage> {
    String str;

  _BarcodePageState(String s ){
    str = s;

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar:  new AppBar(title: new Text("Bar code"),),
      body: new Text(str),
    );
  }

}
```

You can find the application in https://github.com/arashbi/flutter_barcode_reader example folder

This is related to my question before, but simpler setup.

Comment: Can you try posting a bit more about what exactly is wrong? Is it something visual?  I tried to reproduce this without your plugin and I'm not seeing anything strange from this code - the new page comes up as expected.

Comment: If it's something visual, perhaps a recording of the unexpected behavior even would explain

Comment: Right. I was not sure how to do that, but I solved the issue. The visual problem is that the second page - with its appbar and all - appears in the middle of the first page, like a widget. If you can imagine that

Answer (score 0):

AFAI understand the problem is that callback is happening in the middle of render pipeline, and it causes the wrong behaviour. The solution is to use either `Future.delayed` or `SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback`

These methods causes the navigation to happen after the render pipeline, and the navigator can do its job properly